# MySQL: aggregate max value after calculation

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an auto scorer for codes, and an overtime penalty strategy for my students: When he submits his code `n` minutes after a given deadline, his score will be multiplied by `(100-min(n, 80))/100`.

`problem` table:

```
id | deadline
 1 | 13:00
```

`user_submission` table:

```
id | uid | problem_id | time  | score
 1 | 101 |          1 | 10:00 | 80
 2 | 101 |          1 | 13:30 | 90
 3 | 102 |          1 | 13:30 | 90
```

Since the second submissions of user 101 and 102 exceeded the deadline by 30 minutes, their score needs to be multiplied by 0.7, which is 90*0.7=63.

Therefore, when querying for the highest score obtained by the user, the result should be as follows:

```
problem_id | uid | max_score
         1 | 101 | 80
         1 | 102 | 63
         2 | ...
```

How to construct this query? I have tried `max()` aggregation, but I could not use the `problem`.`deadline` field well.

Comment: Please clarify your formula, which seems to say that the multiplying factor can never be less than 80/100.

Comment: You need to use a condition (case or if()) within the max function.

Comment: @Shadow But how can I get the `deadline` field corresponding to each user's submission ? Will there be any performance issues if I do a subquery for each row during aggregation?

Comment: your `deadline` and `time`    field requires a date, not just an hour

Comment: @RickDou you get the submission deadline as you get data from any other table: either using join or subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following approach:

```sql
SELECT
    us.problem_id,
    us.uid,
    MAX(us.Score * CASE WHEN TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(us.time, p.deadline)) > 0
                        THEN 1.0 - LEAST(80.0, TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(us.time, p.deadline))) / 100.0
                        ELSE 1.0 END) AS max_score
FROM user_submission us
INNER JOIN problem p
    ON p.id = us.problem_id
GROUP BY
    us.problem_id,
    us.uid;
```

The expression:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(us.time, p.deadline))
```

will be a positive number whenever any given answer happen to be past the deadline.  In that case, we multiply the score by your formula `100-min(n, 80) / 100`.  Note that we use the `LEAST()` scalar function here, not `MIN()`, as the latter is strictly an *aggregate* function.

Comment: I'm sorry for that I still made a mistake in the formula. It should actually be (100-min(n, 80)) / 100. However, I have understood your method! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @RickDou You're right, and I have updated my answer.